# Is it wise to use fractional / decimal pixels for borders in css?

Tags: css, border, pixel

I have various instances in my design that call for

```
border-right: 1.5px solid black;
border-bottom: 1.5px solid black;
```

etc...

I also have design that needs thinner lines: at `1px`.

However, it seems the browser may round the decimal, as I'm not seeing much differentiation between the two (if any).

Should I just be using `2px` and `1px` instead, or is there a better way to pull this off?

A designer I'm helping is very adamant about the `1.5px` line width.

Any help, much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure how your designer is visualising the 1.5px. I mean, _of course_ the value is rounded to whole pixels. Unless you have a high-resolution device like a phone or a printer. But those edge-cases aside... oh, wait.

Comment: It will be rounded to an integer number of pixels always...

Comment: @MrLister, Sarcasm? You're saying it should work because those are not 'edge cases' ?

Comment: Seriously now, if this is meant for something to be printed, CSS units like `pt` would probably be better.

Comment: Not meant for print. Just for display in browser.

Comment: OK. In that case, there's no such thing as half a pixel. Fractional pixels will be rounded, end of story. Please note, however, that some browsers will try to keep things lined up with some properties. In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/3rm507mv/1/) where I've given the paragraphs a margin of 1.25px, most margins will be 1 pixel, but one in every four margins will be 2 pixels!

Comment: Thanks.  Is there another value I could use? Pt , em, etc? Use css transform / scale?

Comment: I suggest you dont, since this can sometimes invoke weird behavior. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47603304

Answer (score 8):

You can use it, but most browsers will round pixel value.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/syndata.html#values

[http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css](http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/)

http://cruft.io/posts/percentage-calculations-in-ie/

**EDIT:** Remember that one CSS pixel is not always equal to one physical screen pixel: [A pixel is not a pixel is not a pixel](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html)

Comment: Is there another value I could use? Pt , em, etc? Use css transform / scale?

Comment: @someoneHere Yes, you can use decimal value with percent, pt, em. But sometimes it can works inconsistently for different browsers.