# Bootstrap 4 table with d-flex and another border color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, bootstrap-4

I'm working with bootstrap 4.0 and i'm trying to use `table-bordered` (changing the color) and `d-flex` with `col-*` to sizing columns.

The thing is, for some reason, all borders are double if I try to change the color.

For example, this is what I'm doing:

```css
table.table-bordered {
  border: 1px solid black;
  }
table.table-bordered > thead > tr > th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  }
table.table-bordered > tbody > tr > td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  }        
div{
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  }
```

```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
   
<div>
   <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="table-danger d-flex">
                <td class="col-6">Cell 1</td>
                <td class="col-6">Cell 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="d-flex">
                <td class="col-6">Cell 3</td>
                <td class="col-6">Cell 5</td>
                
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

As you can see in the example the borders are double.

With `w-*` clases it works ok, but they are less versatile

How can I fix this problem with `d-flex` and `col-*` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `border-collapse` HTML tables "automatically" handle the repeating borders around adjacent rows & cells as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35678354/171456).

Flexbox doesn't conditionally render specific left/right/top/bottom margins on each cell so it's rendering the full border which doubles-up on the bottom of each row, and around the table.

To fix this you'd need to render only the left and top borders on the `tbody`, then only the right and bottom borders on the `td` cells.

```
table.table-bordered {
     border-width: 0;
}

table.table-bordered tbody {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px  0   0  1px;
}

table.table-bordered td {
    border-color: black;    
    border-width:  0  1px 1px  0;
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/JAst9a3XHr

Comment: Thanks so much, if you can, add `border: none;` to `table.table-bordered`, with that the solution is just perfect!

Comment: Thank you, and yes that is also needed.

Answer (score 2):

Use borders for only td with negative margin and remove borders for table and th

```css
table.table-bordered > tbody > tr > td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin:-0.5px;
}        
div{
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
   
<div>
   <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="table-danger d-flex">
                <td class="col-6">Cell 1</td>
                <td class="col-6">Cell 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="d-flex">
                <td class="col-6">Cell 3</td>
                <td class="col-6">Cell 5</td>
                
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```