# Remove border when hover on item

Tags: html, css

I want red border to be removed when hover on each item.

As you can see from the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lilpenguin/7bmv2aej/10/) that I've attached here. It only worked on the first div on left, and also the rest of the div on the right.

The reason I do it this way is because I want it to be flexible so that I can add or remove on HTML without affecting CSS part.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.item {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  flex: 0 0 15%;
}
.item-left + .item-right {
  margin-left: auto;
}
.item-left{
 border-left:1px solid red;
}
.item-left:first-of-type{
 border:none;
}
.item-left:last-of-type{
 border-right:1px solid red;
}
.item-right{
 border-left:1px solid red;
}
.item:hover{
 /* box-shadow: x y blur spread color; */
 box-shadow:0px 0px 0px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
 z-index:1;
}
.item:hover + .item.item-left, .item.item-right {
    border:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="bottom" class="bottom">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a class="item item-left">
      <div class="item-label">Left</div>
    </a>
    <a class="item item-left">
      <div class="item-label">Left</div>
    </a>
    <a class="item item-left">
      <div class="item-label">Left</div>
    </a>
    <a class="item item-right">
      <div class="item-label">Right</div>
    </a>
    <a class="item item-right">
      <div class="item-label">Right</div>
    </a>
    <a class="item item-right">
      <div class="item-label">Right</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I can see the red border only on second and third elements in the fiddle. So what do you mean by remove red border which does not exist?

Comment: I want the border of second and third to be removed when hover on each of it. Just like when you hover on the first item.

Comment: You need pure css solution?

Comment: Yes. Pure CSS. As you can see from the script above, it only works on the element comes after it but not the previous one.

Comment: @Zze In this case, there's  gap between two groups of items, which complicates the sibling selector method.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210033/using-only-css-show-div-on-hover-over-a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Borders on adjacent items [can be tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35678353/how-to-create-collapsed-borders-around-flex-items-and-their-container), especially if those borders change when hovering over an item.

It might work to use `outline` instead of `border`. Outlines "never take up space, as they are drawn outside of an element's content," so they won't get doubled up (see [outline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline)).

Outlines appear on *all sides* of an element, as opposed to borders that can be placed on *specific sides* (e.g. left, right, top, bottom). Setting `overflow:hidden` on the `.wrapper` hides the outlines on the outer edges. That way, only the outlines between items are visible.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightblue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  flex: 0 0 15%;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.item-left+.item-right {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.item:hover {
  z-index: 1;
  outline: none;
  background-color: mediumseagreen;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="bottom" class="bottom">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a class="item item-left">
      <div class="item-label">Left</div>
    </a>
    <a class="item item-left">
      <div class="item-label">Left</div>
    </a>
    <a class="item item-left">
      <div class="item-label">Left</div>
    </a>
    <a class="item item-right">
      <div class="item-label">Right</div>
    </a>
    <a class="item item-right">
      <div class="item-label">Right</div>
    </a>
    <a class="item item-right">
      <div class="item-label">Right</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this in your css

```
.item:hover{
  border:none;
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.item {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  flex: 0 0 15%;
}
.item-left + .item-right {
  margin-left: auto;
}
.item-left{
 border-left:1px solid red;
}
.item-left:first-of-type{
 border:none;
}
/*.item-left:last-of-type{
 border-right:1px solid red;
}*/

.last-left{
 border-right:1px solid red;
}

.item-right{
 border-left:1px solid red;
}
.item:hover{
 /* box-shadow: x y blur spread color; */
 box-shadow:0px 0px 0px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
 z-index:1;
}
.item:hover + .item.item-left, .item.item-right, .item:hover {
    border:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="bottom" class="bottom">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a class="item item-left">
      <div class="item-label">Left</div>
    </a>
    <a class="item item-left">
      <div class="item-label">Left</div>
    </a>
    <a class="item item-left last-left">
      <div class="item-label">Left</div>
    </a>
    <a class="item item-right">
      <div class="item-label">Right</div>
    </a>
    <a class="item item-right">
      <div class="item-label">Right</div>
    </a>
    <a class="item item-right">
      <div class="item-label">Right</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You might consider `border-color:transparent` instead of `border:none` so that the position of the label doesn't shift on hover.

Comment: btw, there is one line of my css (.item-left:last-of-type) is not working. Do you mind to help me take a look on that? I want to add border right on the last item-left but it seems not working.

Comment: @showdev thanks for that. I will change on my script. :-)

Comment: @StacieT. [`last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) does not take classes into consideration, only the element type (e.g. `<div>`). See [How do I select the “last child” with a specific class name in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211453/css-how-to-say-classlast-of-type-classes-not-elements)

Comment: @showdev I tried all possible which is `border:0px solid #fff;`,`border:none` and `border:1px solid transparent;` but almost your suggestion also okay.

Comment: @StacieT. check the updated answer. Already @showdev mentioned in comment class of last-of-type will be not work, so I add additional class name for last `item-left` class it will be work's now.

Comment: @UdhayTitus I tried to change css style for border style. But it's not working now after I changed it. Did i do it wrongly? So sorry. I'm very new to css and i'm quite confused with the (+) on css. Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/lilpenguin/7bmv2aej/32/

Comment: @UdhayTitus the previous fiddle was different from this. I want both left and right border to be gone when hover. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: yes you can do by using `border:none` on hover it will be works

Comment: do you mind to help me take a look on this? https://jsfiddle.net/lilpenguin/7bmv2aej/36/
the right one is working now. but why is the left one not working? while they are using the same code?

Comment: as you can see, the border won't disappear when hover on the left side.