# Weird table pixel bug in Chrome

Tags: html, css

[image]

I am encountering strange pixel discrepancy in Google Chrome (*not* Firefox). See above image or run the code snippet below.

In red border can be seen the table. Orange: div in td. Grey: td. I expect both to have the same height. Why dont they? The left one is half a pixel bigger. If you zoom it with Chrome, the difference resolves. Is this some kind of bug in Chrome? Do I have to use px as a measurement instead? I do not want to, since I am rendering a to-be-printed page here.

I tried hard to remove any unnecessary parts.

```css
  * {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }
  #wrapper1 {
    padding-top: 5mm;
    background:lightblue;
   }
   #wrapper2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background:lightgrey;
  }
   table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-top:7mm;
   } 
   td, .box {
    width:12mm;
    height:12mm;
   }
   td {
    background:grey;
   }
   .box {
    background:orange;
   }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper1">
   <div id="wrapper2">
      <table>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <div  class="box"></div>
               </td>
               <td></td>
            </tr>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use physical sizes on a screen.

Comment: Along the lines of the comment and answer, you should look at [the W3C's statement on using mm for sizing on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47603304/weird-table-pixel-bug-in-chrome) (hint: don't).

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297619/using-cm-mm-on-the-css-of-a-web-app-that-replicates-paper-interaction-is-a-good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mm` units do not convert into a whole number of pixels. For example, `12mm` is `45.354330709px`. Unfortunately, browsers handle rounding differently since [no CSS spec is provided](https://www.palantir.net/blog/responsive-design-s-dirty-little-secret) for how it should be done.

As an example, I have converted your `mm` units to use `px`. I scaled it up/down by a factor of 10 and no longer see a difference in where the borders are placed.

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#wrapper1 {
  padding-top: 5mm;
  background:lightblue;
}
#wrapper2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background:lightgrey;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-top:70px;
} 
td, .box {
  width:120px;
  height:120px;
}
td {
  background:grey;
}
.box {
  background:orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper1">
   <div id="wrapper2">
      <table>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <div  class="box"></div>
               </td>
               <td></td>
            </tr>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Along the same line, look at [the W3C's statement on using mm for sizing on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47603304/weird-table-pixel-bug-in-chrome) (hint: don't).

Comment: So Chrome has difficulties rendering pixels with decimals in general? Should I only use integer pixels? Anyway, I cannot reproduce the inital problem with pixels, so this is most likely the correct answer. thanks

Comment: @Blauhirn I've encountered the same issue in some of my own work that has a responsive design. I've tried using JavaScript to line everything up but thus far haven't found any workarounds. Honestly I just learned to live with it. If something looks really offensive I'll tweak my design to work without partial pixels.